# Use of Poincare inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded domain. Then using
Poincare-Wirtinger, one can prove that for functions $f \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ there exists $C>0$ such that

$$\|u\|_{L^{2}}^{2} \le C\|u'\|_{L^{2}}^{2} + C\left( \int u(x)~dx
 \right)^{2}.  $$

**Question:** Suppose we have a function $u$ which satisfies

$$  \|u'\|_{L^{2}}^{2} + \left( \int u(x)~dx \right)^{2} \le C .          
 $$

Can we conclude that $u \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$? The reason I am not sure is because in order for us to use the first inequality we need that $u \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ which a-priori we don't have. I think the statement could be true and we can prove it by some density argument but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Your inequality is not homogeneous, I suppose the $L^2$ norms should be squared?

Comment: Yes sorry that is right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\Omega$ has regular boundary (say Lipshitz) you can use the fact that since $u' \in L^2(\Omega)$ then by Sobolev-Morrey inequality, $u\in C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega)$ for some $\alpha>0$, and so is bounded on $\Omega$. This implies that $u\in L^2$ since $\Omega$ is bounded.

Comment: Wouldn't assuming $u \in H^1$ imply $u \in L^2$ by definition? Also, one usually assume $L^1_{loc}$ when talking about weak differentiablity instead of $L^1$. In more rigirous from: Given $u \in L^1_{loc}$ satisfying $u' \in L^2$ and the second inequality, do we already have $u \in H^1$? Also, you need $u$ to be continuous up to the boundary to conclude boundedness (for example, by using Hölder continuity from Morrey).

Comment: Yes, you are right, I wanted first to write $\dot{H}^1$. I will rewrite the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If $u$ satisfies this second inequality, we should already have $u \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ or $u \in C^1(\Omega) \subseteq W^{1,2}(\Omega) $, or else how do you define $u'$ inside the $L^2$ norm?

Comment: $u'$ could be understood in the distributional or weak sense. I am not convinced that $u$ should necessarily be in $C^1$ or $W^{1,2}$ from your answer

Comment: I'm not really familiar with distributions but talking about the weak case, if $u'$ is the derivative of $u$ in the weak sense this immediately tells us that $u \in W^{1,2}(\Omega) $ by the definition of the weak derivative. That is, $u$ is weakly differentiable if there exists some $g \in L^2$ such that $\int u\phi'=-\int g\phi  $ for every $ \phi \in C_c^\infty $. Then $u' =g$ in the weak sense.

Comment: How does this follow from the definition? This would tell us that $(u, \phi)_{L^{2}} \le C$ for any $\phi$ which is a derivative of some $\psi \in C^{\infty}_{c}$. But not that $(u,u)_{L^{2}} \le C$.

Comment: I think you should check the definition of the Sobolev space https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space.

Comment: It says that we need $\|u\|_{L^{2}} + \|u'\|_{L^{2}} \le C$ in order to say $u \in W^{1,2}$.

Comment: From your initial question, we have some $u$ satisfying the given inequality, which itself includes $u'$. And I'm saying that if $u'$ denotes the derivative in the weak sense, that means the weak derivative exists, which trivially concludes to $u \in W^{1,2}$.

Comment: But this is not obvious from the definition. How do you know that $u \in L^{2}$ just from $u' \in L^{2}$?

Comment: First of all I'm only talking about the weak sense. And if $u'$ exists, that means $u \in W^{1,2} \subseteq L^2$

Comment: The weak derivative is defined for $u \in L^{1}_{loc}$. Why isn't it possible to have $u' \in L^{2}$ but $u \notin L^{2}$?

Comment: $u \in W^{1,2}$ requires both $u, u'$ to have finite $L^{2}$ norm. You are saying that $u' \in L^{2} \implies u \in L^{2}$ which I am not convinced of.

Comment: Ok, I see that we have seen different definitions of $W^{1,2}$. I've come across a definition that says $W^{1,2}$ is a subspace of $L^2$ and not $L^1_loc$. That's why I was seeing this as a trivial result all this time.

Comment: Wikipedia has this definition as well. Meaning the elements of $W^{1,2}$ are the elements of $L^2$ such that etc.

Comment: Ah I see the confusion now